# How was a retinal scan possible when the subject had closed eyes?

Tags: plot-explanation, fast-and-furious-franchise, hobbs-and-shaw

In [*Fast & Furious Presents: Hobbs & Shaw*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbs_%26_Shaw), Shaw used a thug's head to pass the retinal scan in this scene:

[image: protagonist presses other character's head on scanner]

How was a retinal scan possible when the subject had closed eyes?

Comment: Worth mentioning: retinal scan != iris scan.

Comment: One possible explanation: The stuntman playing the "thug" wasn't supposed to have closed eyes in that scene (or it wasn't supposed to be visible that they were closed), and it just wasn't picked up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's not possible

But, the panel had just received **9 headbutts** before finally opening on the 10th go.

Perhaps, the panel simply malfunctioned and opened as a result of the repeated hits, rather than the retinal scan itself.

For the purpose of the joke, we just have to accept that's what happened.

If the film was *fully grounded in reality* then Jason would probably have to find a way to hold the guards eyelids open, and ensure the eyeball hasn't rolled back, or perhaps remove the eyeball completely, in order to active the scanner.

These options would probably slow the pace of the scene too much, and eyeball removal is probably too gory for the film.